# Can the same dataset be described as Chaotic & Pareto/ Power law distribution?

Tags: st.statistics, data-analysis, pattern-matching, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to abstract the mathematical part of the problem as much as possible before the details follow,
There's this dynamic data set that's $O(2^{32})$, a recent result described it as a power-law distribution, as average is approaching $1-2$ with a peak at $100$ as said. I was just motivated by the fact that there is a subset known to have sometimes values of $O(10^5)$ inside, and the 1st lesson on Statistics is that average is not enough to represent the data in such cases. Then I found previous results describing the same dataset as:

- > "is impossible to be modeled mathematically, since it is purely chaotic" (Stanford report Dec2015)
- > "Nevertheless, in the above graph there’s a distinct linear formation within the phenomenal chaos" (2017).

I came to this group to ask the Scientific opinion of the most specialized, all the complete files r downloadable & available online.

**References**

[The Stanford Report poster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwyO4.jpg)

[The median results 2017, although I think it has 2 groups/clusters one with a linearly increasing median & one adjacent to the X-axis (the majority by the newer results)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNUAu.jpg)

[a fig From
"Implementing A Church–Turing Deutsch Principle Machine on a Blockchain", Konstantinos Sgantzos,Department of Computer Science and Biomedical Informatics
, University of Thessaly, Lamia, Greece,17-07-2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFugn.jpg)

[The Utreexo graph 2019, with green text & colored lines added by me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYNSi.jpg)

.
Ps.
I added Laplace Transformation as a keyword because it is stated in the full copy of the Stanford report that it was used in processing the data set:

*Two methods of doing this are either (1) entirely empirically or (2) based on a fitted distribution.
The former case is simply a matter of sorting the lifespan dataset and splitting it into ten equally
sized groups. The latter requires more processing. Understanding that the data should show signs
of a Laplace or exponential distribution based the standard application of those distributions, the
first step was to cluster the lifespan set using k-median (`1 penalty function) clustering. From
there, we fitted either a Normal, Laplace, or Exponential (whichever was most likely) distribution
to each cluster using maximum likelihood estimation and then formed a global distribution as a
weighted sum.*

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by a "chaotic" data set? white noise?

Comment: The term "Chaotic" came from the papers/reports not me, I understand it as "cannot be mathematically predicted or fitted in a known formula/distribution/curve/..."; usually refers to  dynamic data

Comment: Do u have an answer to the question? Howcome nobody in a math specialized group like this is willing to answer & clarify a scientific issue????Who just downgraded the Q without even answering it?!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest exploring  the alpha-stable models.
Anytime, data are this skewed maybe that is the way to go. I would consult with John Nolan of American University, a real expert and a software writer in this area.

Comment: The curves here r quite different than both results I think?httpss://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution

Comment: Also, in general do u agree with me that it's kind of strange that the Utreexo team build their MIT licenced & widely funded project assuming most UTXOs will have lifespan 1-2 ( with a little peak at 100 as they say). When I pursued much on the discussion & found the Stanford report, they just stopped replying (in fact it seemed like everyone every where did so)